# Call a rest web api in asp.net and receive error

Tags: asp.net, post, controller, token, webapi

Hi I want to call a rest Web Api and I use asp.net MVC+Web Api.
I write a get Token Method like below :

```
      public TokenViewModel GetToken()
    {
        //string Result = string.Empty;
        TokenViewModel token = null;
        string baseAddress = "http://$$$$$$$$$$/api/security/login";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var url = new Uri(baseAddress);
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters.Add("UserName", "###");
                parameters.Add("Password", "$$$");
                HttpContent DictionaryItems = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
                form.Add(DictionaryItems, "model");


                var response = client.PostAsync(url.ToString(), form,            System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

                if (response.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //Get body
                    var bodyRes = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenViewModel>(bodyRes);
                    //Get Header
                    //   var headers = response.Result.Headers.GetValues("appToken");
                }
                else
                {
                    var a = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return token;

        }

    }
```

And also webController:

```
  namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{

public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly GetToken_BLL _tokenService;
    public WebApiController(GetToken_BLL tokenService)
    {

        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public object Verfiybll { get; private set; }

    public class stcAPIMessage
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    }

  [HttpPost]
  [Route("api/Token")]
    public IHttpActionResult Token()
    {
        stcAPIMessage message = new stcAPIMessage();
        GetToken_BLL tokenbll = new GetToken_BLL();
        var result = tokenbll.GetToken();

        if (result == null)
        {
            message.Message = "error in recieveing token";
            message.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Content(message.StatusCode, message.Message);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Token))
        {
            message.Message = "Error";
            message.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Content(message.StatusCode, message.Message);
        }
        return Ok(result);
     }

  }
}
```

When I run the program it throw out error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Web ApiController'.
> Make sure  that the controller has a parameter less public constructor.
> System. Invalid Operation Exception  Type 'WebAPI.Controllers.
> Web ApiController' does not have a default constructor
> System.

Comment: Can you post controller too, pls and ecurity/login api header.

Comment: I copied my whole controller as you wish!

Comment: Thanks, and show login Api too.

Comment: sorry I wrote a method to get token  and an web api to call that method and also a view (token view model) for the output

Answer (score 0):

The parameter less constructor error is common in ASP.NET web applications that use dependency injection.

I have noticed there is a constructor parameter being used:

```
GetToken_BLL _tokenService
```

Use a dependency injection resolver for the type GetToken_BLL so that the parameter _tokenService can be instantiated.